# How to write multiple images to a HttpUrlConnection's OutputStream along with other request parameters in Android Studio?

Tags: java, php, android, laravel

**TL;DR** How do I upload images as an array to a request body with other request parameters using HttpUrlConnection?

Hello, I'm developing an app that surveys the deadweight of a vessel. To survey the weights of a room, each item's weight needs to be recorded along with other attributes of the item. The user should be able to upload multiple images of this item. The item's attributes and images will be uploaded to a server where it will be stored in a database. The web application is coded using Laravel and the route for submitting an item for a room is as follows:

```
public function roomSurvey(Request $request){
     if(Auth::check()){
       //Check if all the parameters are there
       if( $request->room_id==null || $request->item_name==null || $request->weight==null || $request->cgabove==null || $request->lcg==null || $request->tcg==null || $request->vcg==null){
         return response()->json(['message'=>'Missing Parameters','request'=>$request->getContent()], 400);
       }
       $commonItem = CommonItem::where('doi', $request->item_name)->first();
       $roomData = RoomData::create([
                      'room_id'  => $request->room_id,
                      'doi_id'   => $commonItem->id,
                      'doi'      => $commonItem->doi,
                      'weight'   => $request->weight,
                      'cgabove'  => $request->cgabove,
                      'lcg'      => $request->lcg,
                      'tcg'      => $request->tcg,
                      'vcg'      => $request->vcg,
                      'v_cg'     => $request->vcg+$request->cgabove,
                      'lmom'     => $request->lcg*$request->weight,
                      'tmom'     => $request->tcg*$request->weight,
                      'vmom'     => $request->vcg*$request->weight,
                      'v_mom'    => ($request->vcg+$request->cgabove)*$request->weight,
                   ]);
       $roomDataLog = RoomDataLog::create([
                      'room_id'  => $request->room_id,
                      'data_id'  => $roomData->id,
                      'doi_id'   => $commonItem->id,
                      'doi'      => $commonItem->doi,
                      'weight'   => $request->weight,
                      'cgabove'  => $request->cgabove,
                      'lcg'      => $request->lcg,
                      'tcg'      => $request->tcg,
                      'vcg'      => $request->vcg,
                      'v_cg'     => $request->vcg+$request->cgabove,
                      'lmom'     => $request->lcg*$request->weight,
                      'tmom'     => $request->tcg*$request->weight,
                      'vmom'     => $request->vcg*$request->weight,
                      'v_mom'    => ($request->vcg+$request->cgabove)*$request->weight,
                      ]);
        //Add images if the user has sent them in the request
       if($request->images && count($request->images) > 0){
         foreach($request->images as $room_data_image){
                $image = $room_data_image;
                $filenameWithExt = $image->getClientOriginalName();
                $imageName = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $imageExt = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $originalName = $imageName.'_'.time().'.'.$imageExt;
                $destination_path = public_path('/roomsdata');
                $image->move($destination_path, $originalName);
                $fileNameToStore = "roomsdata/".$originalName;
                RoomDataImage::create([
                  'room_data_id' => $roomData->id,
                  'image' => $fileNameToStore
                ]);
         }
       }
       return response()->json(['data'=>$roomData, 'message'=>'Survey Submitted'], 201);
    }else{
      return response()->json(['message'=>'User is not authenticated'], 403);
     }
   }
```

The part to focus on is:

```
//Add images if the user has sent them in the request
       if($request->images && count($request->images) > 0){
         foreach($request->images as $room_data_image){
                $image = $room_data_image;
                $filenameWithExt = $image->getClientOriginalName();
                $imageName = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $imageExt = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $originalName = $imageName.'_'.time().'.'.$imageExt;
                $destination_path = public_path('/roomsdata');
                $image->move($destination_path, $originalName);
                $fileNameToStore = "roomsdata/".$originalName;
                RoomDataImage::create([
                  'room_data_id' => $roomData->id,
                  'image' => $fileNameToStore
                ]);
         }
       }
```

At the moment the app can upload items if images are not sent in the request body. An AsyncTask is executed when the submit button is clicked and a POST request is sent to the server to submit an item. It returns success. The AsyncTask is a subclass in the Activity for entering the item's data. The doInBackground method does the following:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            URL downloadUrl = urls[0];
            String message = null;

            String json = HttpDownloader.submitItemPostRequest(downloadUrl,doi,weight,cgAboveValue,lcgValue,tcgValue,vcgValue);
            Log.i("ItemActivity.java", "Response: " + json);

            if(json.equals(HttpDownloader.LOGGED_OUT)){
                return message;
            }
            else if(json.equals(HttpDownloader.ERROR)){
                return message;
            }

            try {
                message = ProcessingJson.submitItem(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return message;
        }
```

The HttpDownloader class sets up the HttpUrlConnection object and writes to it's output stream and handles the InputStream:

```
public static String submitItemPostRequest(URL url,String doi, String weight,String cgAbove, String lcg,String tcg, String vcg){

        /*
        How to make POST request:
        1. Create a HttpURLConnection object
        2. Set Method type
        3. setDoOutput(true) if sending data
        4. Set content-type ="application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        5. Create OutputStream Object
        6. Write json object to output stream
        7. Force any buffered output bytes
        8. Close output stream and release system resources
        9. Get the response code
        10.Create a StringBuilder object
        11.Get input stream from POST request
        12.Read input stream line-by-line
        13.Append line to StringBuilder
        14.Close Buffered Reader
        15.Return StringBuilder as a string
        */

        String charset = "UTF-8";

        String data = "";

        data+="item_name="+doi;
        data+="&weight="+weight;
        data+="&cgabove="+cgAbove;
        data+="&lcg="+lcg;
        data+="&tcg="+tcg;
        data+="&vcg="+vcg;
        // Testing uploading images

        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty(charset,"utf-8");

            OutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            // Testing uploading images
            wr.write(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            response = new StringBuilder();
            if(responseCode==HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED){
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;

                while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
            } else if(responseCode==HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN){
                response.append(LOGGED_OUT);
                urlConnection.disconnect();
                error=false;
                return response.toString();
            } else{
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        urlConnection.getErrorStream()));
                String inputLine;

                while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                response.append(ERROR);
                error=true;
                urlConnection.disconnect();
                return response.toString();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
```

My question is how do I upload multiple images to this OutputStream? Should I add to the String variable `data` as such `data += "&images=";` then after this write to the OutputStream the data bytes for an image using a URI. How do I write to the OutputStream to let it know that I'm sending an a request parameter as an array.

I have tried writing the bytes of an image to the OutputStream before but the server responds with:

```
parameter must be an array or an object that implements countable
```

Comment: Have you considered using a more modern HTTP API? OkHttp, or perhaps Retrofit, are likely candidates.

Comment: name your variable `images[]` and not `images` or even better, give each image variable an index `images[0]=....&images[1]=...`

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the quick response. My only issue with that is I use multiple AsyncTask's calling different routes on the web application. Could I have Retrofit or OkHttp working alongside the requests already there? Also do you have any links to examples of either of those suggestions for uploading images? Thanks again

Comment: @N69S Thanks for the reply. So I could add to the `data` String `images[0]` then write the image as bytes? Then continue for however many images I need?

Comment: "My only issue with that is I use multiple AsyncTask's calling different routes on the web application" -- `AsyncTask` has been deprecated, and it has not been a good choice for years. "Could I have Retrofit or OkHttp working alongside the requests already there?" -- presumably, yes. "Also do you have any links to examples of either of those suggestions for uploading images?" -- https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#posting-a-file-kt-java https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#posting-a-multipart-request-kt-java

Comment: @CommonsWare I did start out using Volley but the documentation for it was abysmal so I switched to AsyncTask. I'll check out these links, thank you.